# TFS 2017- Release deploy app to IIS under a website

Tags: asp.net, iis, tfs, release, webdeploy

I am using TFS 2017 build and realease to deploy a website,
In my IIS i have the following Structure

```
 - WebsiteHost
   - ApplicationToDeploy
```

I am using `Deploy IIS App` step on TFS realease definition

**Question**: how can I tell the realease build to update `ApplicationToDeploy` under `WebsiteHost`? Right now it creates a new Website on `WebsiteHost` level which i don't want. I tried **WebsiteHost\ApplicationToDeploy** in Host name field in the task but that just created a website with Host name **WebsiteHost\ApplicationToDeploy**. Any Ideas?

Hope I made my issue clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my test, you just need to specify the **Website name** in `Deploy IIS App` step, then it will automatically update the website once any changes are checked in with the CI/CD definitions set.

Assuming the Website name is **ApplicationToDeploy**, just specify the name under `Deployment > Website name`

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Make sure the website is existing there, you check in IIS manager.

[image]

Comment: So if a website exists i don't need manage IIS app Task? Just Deployment?

Comment: Also I am getting this error ERROR_SITE_DOES_NOT_EXISTMore Information: Site 'ApplicationToDeploy' does not exist.

Comment: @WojtekT Just check IIS, make sure the site exists there

Comment: It does It's a App under WebsiteHost Site

Comment: @WojtekT Could you please capture the screenshot for the IIS site and build steps,  and provide any other details to reproduce this issue for further troubleshoot.

Comment: I had a few more steps to my relaesae definition, but now i encountered another problem Config File
   `\\?\C:\inetpub\WebSiteHost \web.config` it does not exitsts, the Path should look like `\\?\C:\inetpub\WebSiteHost\ApplicationToDeploy\web.config` How could i change the path so the app's webconifg does not inherit parents?

Comment: @WojtekT I suggest you open a new thread for the new problem as one thread one question. Thus much more people will see the question and the problem can be solved faster. This can be also beneficial to other community members reading the thread.