# TFS-2017 web interface issues

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have created a release pipeline in TFS web interface. Instead of default website, I have created a new website in IIS in dev server.

How to configure this website in IIS WEB APP MANAGE and IIS Web App Deploy what is the path I have to give in Virtual Application in IIS WEB APP MANAGE and IIS Web App Deploy in TFS web interface.

Comment: I understood nothing. please explain further and separate by comma or paragraphs

Answer (score 0):

**IIS Web App Manage:**

Creating an IIS Web Site and Application Pool. Typically this is only needed the first time deploying to a target machine.

Example: To create an application Site/Application enter /Application as the Virtual path . The parent website should be already existing.

**IIS Web App Deploy:**

If you have created the web site/application, then you just need to deploy it directly with IIS Web App Deployment task. 
You can reference this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45706103/7466674